# why PF_RING is more used then DPDK?

Tags: dpdk, pf-ring

I am trying to choose which one to use for my project. After short resource I found that most of the companies are using PF_RING and not "Data Plane Development Kit" platform. Why?

Comment: I think that's kind of wrong. First of all, we should be comparing DPDK to PF_RING ZC. The ZC version is *not* open-source and needs a license. Secondly, I think that DPDK is much more widely used (OVS, TRex) - even googling for projects gives more results.  
It really depends on the use case, but for best performance and support (from both software and hardware vendors) DPDK seems like a better choice.   
Admittedly, it's kind of a huge toolkit and maybe too big for smaller projects, but the documentation is pretty good, too.

Answer (score -2):

Because using PF_RING is much easier to use and more portable than using DPDK which is a tool to solve specific problems.

If you are asking this kind of question, I think you need neither of these.

Comment: Is it more portable? PF_RING is Linux only from what I've read, while DPDK can run on multiple platforms.

Also, when you're choosing a technology you need you do research and compare solutions. OP may perfectly need it.

It does seem easier to use, tho. I suffered a bit when trying to use DPDK in a work project, I ended up ditching the efforts for AF_XDP.